# share folders on windows azure

Tags: azure

I recently opened an Windows Azure account, and setup a Azure Virtual Machine. I would like to share few folders in the virtual machine and have those accessed locally on my pc. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty? Install the Skydrive client, and select "Make files on this PC available to me on my other devices" during the install.

You could also setup some sort of RDP solution, but the above is fastest.

Answer (score 0):

You could enable the FTP server feature in the VM. I once wrote a manual how to do so [on my blog](http://nicoploner.blogspot.de/2010/12/ftp-server-on-windows-azure-from.html) - you could adapt it to current OSs that run on Azure VMs.